# Generating pdf from webpage in php

Tags: php, apache2, wkhtmltopdf

how can I execute command `wkhtmltopdf http://google.com /tmp/test.pdf` from server ie http://localhost/test.php, when I do it from command line it works. I tried system() and exec() functions but did not work. When I use `system('touch /tmp/test')` file is created. What stops wkhtmltopdf? Is it php, apache?

Comment: Was it install on the server? And was it added to the path for execution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user the script is running as knows where wkhtmltopdf bin is.

You can find out where it is with the which command.

```
which wkhtmltopdf
```

Also you can get the return status of a command by setting a variable equal to it 
e.g.

```
$last_line = system('ls');
echo $last_line
```

Comment: Using this on server gives me /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: So where ever you are using wkhtmltopdf give it the full path:         system('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://google.com /tmp/test.pdf');

Comment: The parser is automatically turning it into a google link so you will have to manually write out the http:// part.